# difference between client and executor in dask

Tags: client, dask, executor, dask-distributed

Executor is the primary entry point for users of distributed.Similarly, Client is the primary entry point for users of dask.distributed.
So, both seem like identical.

In dask, can both be used interchangeably ?
If yes,what is the use case to use either executor or client ?

Comment: Where do you find a mention of "executor"? Perhaps you are reading old documentation. Also, I don't understand what you mean mean by "entry point" here.

Comment: https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.5/executor.html      
https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html
These documentations have these statements.

Answer (score 0):

The short and simplest answer: the *executor* is a deprecated term for the thing that is now known as the *client*. Refer only to the client. Your documentation page is for versioin 1.9, but `distributed` is now at version `1.22`.